# How to prevent redux-saga from calling my api call twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga to handle my API calls while sign-in in a new user into my app. But, my saga watcher calls my API twice. The first time, the API fetches data correctly and during the second time, It is giving me an Error 400.

I tried using the takeLatest saga effect. It didn't work.

I also tried this custom saga effect.
import { call, fork, take } from "redux-saga/effects";

```
export function* takeOneAndBlock(pattern, worker, ...args) {
  const task = yield fork(function*() {
    while (true) {
      const action = yield take(pattern);
      yield call(worker, ...args, action);
    }
  });
  return task;
}
```

It prevents API from rendering twice. but blocks all other calls of my session and token management

Here's is code for my sign in saga.

```
signInSaga.js

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import { put, call, takeEvery, delay } from "redux-saga/effects";


import {
  AUTHENTICATE_USER,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  SET_ERRORS,
  AUTH_INITIATE_LOGOUT,
  AUTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT
} from "../actions/types";
import * as actions from "../actions/signInActions";
//import qs library from es6 to stringify form data
import qs from "qs";
// import configured axios from "axios_api file";
import api from "../apis/axios_api";

/** function that returns data for token and session management */
function getToken() {
  //TODO: Add logic to get jwt token using username and password
  const expiresIn = 60 * 1000; // in milli seconds
  const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiresIn);
  return {
    token: "fakeToken",
    userId: "fakeUserId",
    expirationDate,
    expiresIn
  };
}

/** function that returns an axios call */
function loginApi(loginData) {
  //Axios doesn't stringify form data by default.
  //Hence, qs library is used to stringify upcoming redux-form data.

  return api.post("/login", qs.stringify(loginData));
}

/** saga worker that is responsible for the side effects */
function* loginEffectSaga(action) {
  try {
    // data that is obtained after axios call
    let history = action.history;

    let { data } = yield call(loginApi, action.payload);

    // dispatch authenticate user action to change redux state
    yield put(actions.authenticateUser(data, history));

    //to set and dispatch session and token management action creators
    const tokenResponse = getToken();
    yield localStorage.setItem("token", tokenResponse.token);
    yield localStorage.setItem("expirationDate", tokenResponse.expirationDate);
    yield localStorage.setItem("userId", tokenResponse.userId);

    yield put(actions.authSuccess(tokenResponse.token, tokenResponse.userId));
    yield put(actions.checkAuthTimeout(tokenResponse.expiresIn));

    //dispatch clear_errors action creator to remove any previous set errors
    yield put({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });

    // redirect to dashboard route after successful Login

    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (e) {
    // catch error on a bad axios call and dispatch set_errors action creator
    yield put({ type: SET_ERRORS, payload: e.response.data });
    console.log("errors", e.response);
  }
}

/**
 * saga watcher that is triggered when dispatching action of type
 * 'AUTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT' and inturn it fires off AUTH_INITIATE_LOGOUT action creator
 */
function* checkAuthTimeout(action) {
  yield delay(action.expirationTime);
  yield put(actions.logout());
}

/**
 * saga watcher that is triggered when dispatching action of type
 * 'AUTH_INITIATE_LOGOUT'
 */
function* logout(action) {
  yield localStorage.removeItem("token");
  yield localStorage.removeItem("expirationDate");
  yield localStorage.removeItem("userId");
  yield put(actions.logoutSucceed());
}

/**
 * saga watcher that is triggered when dispatching action of type
 * 'SET_AUTHENTICATED'
 */
export function* loginWatcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(AUTHENTICATE_USER, loginEffectSaga);
}

export function* logoutWatcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(AUTH_INITIATE_LOGOUT, logout);
}

export function* checkAuthWatcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(AUTH_CHECK_TIMEOUT, checkAuthTimeout);
}
```

//rootSaga.js

```
import { all, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as signInSagas from "./signInSaga";
import * as signUpSagas from "./signUpSaga";
import * as forgotPasswordSagas from "./forgotPasswordSaga";

// import watchers from other files
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(
    [
      ...Object.values(signInSagas),
      ...Object.values(signUpSagas),
      ...Object.values(forgotPasswordSagas)
    ].map(fork)
  );
}
```

//index.js

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your saga logic is wrong. Maybe the part that dispatches the action could be wrong.

Or you can change sign-in watcher like this,

```js
export function* loginWatcherSaga() {
  while(true) {
    const authAction = yield take(AUTHENTICATE_USER);
    yield fork(loginEffectSaga, authAction);
    const action = yield take([AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS, AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE]);
    // ... your logic
}
```

In this way, second `take` guarantees block other action types until `loginEffectSaga' is complete.

If you don't need other logic after `loginEffectSaga`, you can change `fork` to `call`.